# Detect whether method "A" is a class vs. instance method?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I have multiple objects in my program, some of them implement method A as a class method (`+ (void)A` ), while some others implement it as member function (`- (void) A`). 
How can I use `respondToSelector:` to figure out whether A is supported as class vs. object by a given object?

Just to be clear; I don't have the instances, I only have the classes,  obtained using [NSBundle classNames:name]. Now, I want to know if I simply can call method `A` on the class, or I need to instantiate the class first  and then call `A` on the instance.

Comment: did u try calling respondsToSelector on class and on object and see how it behaves ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ([[NSBundle classNamed:name] respondsToSelector:@selector(A)]){
  //Your class responds to the selector i.e. its a class method
} else if ([[NSBundle classNamed:name] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(A)]){
  //Your class' instances respond to the selector, i.e. its an instance method
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can ask an object for its class using its `class` method/property. The class is represented by an object (of class `Class`). Like other objects, class objects understand the `respondsToSelector:` message.

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(A)]) {
    [object A];
} else if ([object.class respondsToSelector:@selector(A)]) {
    [object.class A];
}
```

P.S. This is probably not good design. You should probably just implement `A` as an instance method everywhere, instead of sometimes as a class method.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear. I don't have the instances yet, I only have the classes,  obtained using [NSBundle classNames:name]. Now, I want to know if I simply can call A on the class, or I need to instantiate the class first  and then call A on the instance.